# Разбивка шестнадцатеричного числа

Tags: c++

Что-то замкнуло, а нагуглить не могу. Имеется шестнадцатеричное число, например, 0x046A. Как его преобразовать в массив 0x00, 0x04, 0x06, 0x0A? Язык C++.

Прошу извинить. По ходу, я ошибся. Нужна строка вида "046A"

Comment: В цикле кладем в элемент массива `X & 0x0F`, потом `X=X>>4` и так пока X не 0. скорее всего писать в массив надо задом наперед

Comment: А можно ли более точно сформулировать вопрос? Есть шестнадцатеричное число - а где оно есть? В переменной или в фале? Какого типа переменная? Далее: что именно получить? Строку char[], разбитую по сколько цифр? Если нет чёткой постановки, не будет и правильного ответа, потому как от этих вопросов полностью зависит решение.

Comment: Есть int 0x046A. Нужно его конвертировать в строку "046A" для последующей посылки в порт

Answer (score 4):

printf("%04X", 0x046A); дает на выходе как раз "046A".

Comment: Столько лишнего тут у Вас. `printf("046A");`

Answer (score 2):

Вариант честный:

```
unsigned short int x = 0x046A;
unsigned char b[4];
b[0] = x&0x0F;
b[1] = (x >> 4)&0x0F;
b[2] = (x >> 8)&0x0F;
b[3] = (x >> 12)&0x0F;
```

В определенной степени хак:

```
union {
    unsigned short int x;
    struct {
        unsigned char b0: 4;
        unsigned char b1: 4;
        unsigned char b2: 4;
        unsigned char b3: 4;
    };
} data;
data.x = 0x046A;

printf("%02X %02X %02X %02X\n",data.b0,data.b1,data.b2,data.b3);
```

**Update** Раз нужна строка - то на чистом :) C++ можно так:

```
ostringstream s;
s << hex << setw(4) << setfill('0') << x;
cout << s.str() << endl;
```

или просто

```
char buffer[5];  
sprintf(buffer,"%04hX",x);
```

Comment: Я ошибся. нужна строка "046A"

Comment: @HermannZheboldov  Проще всего - `sprintf(buffer,"%04X",x)` :)  Посложнее, но зато pure C++ -  `ostringstream s;
    s << hex << setw(4) << setfill('0') << x;
    cout << s.str() << endl;`

Comment: Ну, вариант с union'ом вроде по стандарту UB, нет? Честный вариант честнее как-то. (Хотя возникает вопрос, а как вфигачить бинарные данные в битовое поле, чтобы стандарт был доволен. `memcpy`?)

Comment: где-то мы уже этот вопрос обсуждали) только там прямой каст указателя был... Стандарт разрешает к char - у что угодно кастовать вроде как.

Comment: @VladD Откровенно говоря, не знаю, потому и написал, что хак...

Comment: @pavel: Ага, обсуждали, помню. Но тут же не `char[]`.

Comment: @Harry: Задал вопрос в чате, подождём, пока подтянутся гуру.

Comment: @VladD Что-то у меня с чатом дружба никак не получается... Как там ваш вопрос найти, не подскажете?

Comment: @Harry: Здесь: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow-- (в самом низу) (вот [точная ссылка](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28901153#28901153), но по ней чат в режиме для чтения.)

Comment: Эта проблема с union называется strict-aliasing и ее ноги растут из оптимизации. Лучше всего внимательно прочесть [ТУТ](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options), перейдя к строкам после -fstrict-aliasing. Краткое резюме -- в данном случае все будет работать, проблема возникает при оптимизации косвенного доступа по указателю (в т.ч. к существенно разным типам в union) / Мое субъективное мнение -- это существенная ошибка в идеологии стандарта и далее в компиляторах.

Comment: @VladD спасибо, нашел :)